# onMouseEnter onMouseLeave Error: Too many re-renders react

Tags: reactjs

so This is my first component where I decelerate my routes. And I decided to make two navigation items. And made some styling. But i get the error to many re-renders. Because I try to add styling with hover effect. I don't want to use css.
This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Products from './Screens/ProductsList';
import Preview from './Screens/Product';
import ProductCreate from './Screens/ProductCreate';
import ProductEdit from './Screens/ProductEdit';
import Home from './Screens/Home';

function App() {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div style={style.navigationContainer}>
        <Link
          onMouseEnter={setHover(true)}
          onMouseLeave={setHover(false)}
          style={hover ? style.hoverNavItem : style.navItem}
          to="/products"
        >
          Products List
        </Link>
        <Link
          onMouseEnter={setHover(true)}
          onMouseLeave={setHover(false)}
          style={hover ? style.hoverNavItem : style.navItem}
          to="/products/create"
        >
          Create Product
        </Link>
      </div>

      <Switch>
        <Route
          key="edit-product"
          path="/products/:id/edit"
          component={ProductEdit}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          key="add-product"
          path="/products/create"
          component={ProductCreate}
        ></Route>
        <Route key="preview" path="/products/:id" component={Preview}></Route>
        <Route key="products" path="/products" component={Products}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can I just ask why you want to use JS instead of CSS for this task? when CSS would be much the preferred option for performance reasons and code simplicity

Comment: I like all in one place, and i need to make styling only for few items, so I don't want to create css file.

Comment: have you used `styled-components` before? They make life super easy, code is super readable and no impact on performance in the same way doing it in pure JS might have

Comment: Never tried, i will read docs, thanks :)

Comment: Remade it with css, now I see it takes less code.

Comment: nice one, good job

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` that will call `setHover` function whenever those events are triggered

Change

```
onMouseEnter={setHover(true)}
onMouseLeave={setHover(false)}
```

to

```
onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
```

Doing `onMouseEnter={setHover(true)}` will immediately call the `setHover` function and update the state instead of waiting for the `onMouseEnter` event. Consequently, your code is stuck in an infinite cycle of update state and re-render

Although, if you just want to apply some style on any element on `hover`, then doing it with CSS is much better than what you are trying to do. There's no need to re-render the component, when it is hovered on, just to update its style.

Also keep in mind that, since you are applying style to both `Link` components when `hover` is true, if you hover over one of the `Link` component, it will set `hover` to true and both `Link` components will be styled.

Comment: this is a good answer and I will upvote as it answers the OP question. I would highly advise the OP to use CSS though as for this task it makes more sense for a number of reasons

Comment: @RedBaron i agree, i have mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: Thanks worked out. Forgot about function call.

Answer (score 3):

You need to trigger the function on event like this `onMouseOver={() => {setHover(true}}` [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-resonance-rru74?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) but with your technique you will have both link change when one is hover